# How to Install RVM and RUBY to the specific user in the salt-minion

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rvm, saltstack

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 for salt-master and salt-minion.When i try to install a package in the salt-minion using salt, it installs only in the system specific. But i need to install in the user specific. How to Install RVM and RUBY to the specific user in the salt-minion?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `user` arg in [`cmd`](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run) state to run it as a specific user, for e.g:

**rvm/init.sls**:

```
curl:
  pkg:
    - installed

rvm:
  cmd:
    - run
    - name: curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
    - user: vagrant
    - unless: test -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
    - require:
      - pkg: curl

rvm_bashrc:
  cmd:
    - run
    - name: echo "[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> $HOME/.bashrc
    - user: vagrant
    - unless: grep ".rvm/scripts/rvm" ~/.bashrc
    - require:
      - cmd: rvm
```

**rvm/ruby/init.sls**:

```
include:
  - rvm

ruby:
  cmd:
    - run
    - name: rvm install 2.1.0
    - user: vagrant
    - unless: test -d $HOME/.rvm/rubies/2.1.0
    - require:
      - cmd: rvm_bashrc
```

Comment: rem@rome:/srv/salt/rvm/ruby$ ls
init.sls
rem@rome:/srv/salt/rvm$ sudo salt '*' state.sls ruby
paris:
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    No matching sls found for 'ruby' in env 'base'

Comment: It should be `sudo salt '*' state.sls rvm.ruby`.

Comment: @quanta- please check this link http://pastebin.com/GpK3EkYK

Comment: @krs: _"The following requisites were not found: cmd: rvm_bashrc"_ --> it seems that you forgot to put this part into `rvm/init.sls`? Could you please show us the content of this file?

Comment: the contents of rvm/init.sls is in http://pastebin.com/8TgkvTeg. Please do check it

Comment: But i am getting problem while i am running sudo salt '*' state.sls rvm.ruby. 

i am succeeded when i am running sudo salt '*' state.sls rvm

i want to do rvm install 2.1.0. please do let me know.

Comment: @quanta- the contents of  rvm/ruby/init.sls is pasted in this link http://pastebin.com/TziEQqUB. please do verify this link

Comment: `sudo salt '*' saltutil.sync_all` and try again.

Comment: while i am running sudo salt '' state.sls rvm.ruby still i am getting the same problem. i had pasted the result here. please do verify this link "http://pastebin.com/xxCUUS0N" and do help me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13080/discussion-between-krs-and-quanta)

Comment: @krs: your last paste has been removed.

Comment: @ quanta http://pastebin.com/xxCUUS0N&quot

Comment: @krs: `cat /path/to/rvm/ruby/init.sls`?

Comment: @quanta- please do verify this link http://pastebin.com/3WNmfZzW for cat /srv/salt/rvm2/ruby/init.sls

Comment: @krs: Since I see you included the `rvm`, so, how about `cat /srv/salt/rvm/init.sls`?

Comment: i have only /srv/salt/rvm2/ruby/init.sls